# SQL overlap statement

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to do overlap in SQL (using postgres) but receive an syntax error. And i do not know why I'm getting error and whats wrong with my SQL Statement

Error text

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" Position: 296

SQL Statement

```
SELECT *,
ARRAY_AGG("reserve"."state_id" ) AS "states" FROM "orders_order"
            JOIN "reserve" ON ("order"."id" = "reserve"."order_id")
GROUP BY "order"."id"

HAVING (NOT (ARRAY_AGG("reserve"."state_id" )&& ['test']::varchar(255)[]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) there are two ways to specify an array:

First with the `array` keyword:

```
array['test']
```

or as a string enclosed with curly braces:

```
'{test}'::text[]
```

In the second case the casting might or might not be needed depending on the context on where it's used.

---

There is no need to cast it to a `varchar(255)[]` array. `text[]` will do just fine - especially when comparing it to the result of an `array_agg()` which returns `text[]` as well.